# Virtual treeview place the vertical scrollbar on right side in the RightToLeft bidimode

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Is it possible to place the vertical scrollbar of Virtual treeview on right side in the RightToLeft bidimode and place it on left side in the LeftToRight mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? If `TVirtualTreeView` uses system scrollbars it could be done with setting appropriate extended style.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  LSB = WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR;
var
  ExStyle: LONG_PTR;
begin
  ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(AVTV.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);

  // Check if RTL alignment specified for you component
  if AVTV.BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft then
    begin
      // If so, then exclude LSB-constant and allow Windows place 
      // scrollbar on the right side of window
      if (ExStyle and LSB) = LSB then
        SetWindowLongPtr(AVTV.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle and not LSB);
    end
  else
  if AVTV.BiDiMode = bdLeftToRight then
    begin
      // The same as operation above but for LTR order
      if (ExStyle and LSB) <> LSB then
        SetWindowLongPtr(AVTV.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle or LSB);
    end;
end;
```

*LSB constant is used to make code more compact in post.*

See also

- [GetWindowLongPtrA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra)
- [SetWindowLongPtrA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra)
- [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles)

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe TVirtualTreeView doesn't use system scrollbars?

Comment: @saeid2014 I tested code with `TVirtualStringTree` downloaded from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/). It works perfectly.

Comment: @saeid2014 if my answer helped you to solve your problem then accept it, please!

Comment: thank you very much Dima. It works correctly but I have used a skin component and when it is active the code doesn't work. The problem is in the component and your code is correct. thanks agian

Comment: @saeid2014 I am glad to help you, but comments sometimes can gone away so click check mark under my answer.

Comment: Would it make sense to have this code directly in Virtual TreeView? If so, please open an issue at GitHub.

Comment: @JoachimMarder I don't think so. Literally, that code breaks down architecture for users with RTL language installed on their computers. For middle-eastern languages vertical scrollbar should be placed at left side of control as people will read text in component from Right-To-Left. That's why it is not appropriate for *all* users that use middle-eastern language. But it could be released as additional feature.

Comment: @Dima there is a problem when tree is in grid mode and has header columns. Please see the screen shot. [here](http://uupload.ir/files/6vmq_vst.png).

Comment: @saeid2014 I'm sorry, but I don't know how to solve this issue. You can create a new question: maybe someone knows this component better than me and will be glad to help you.